# Which function is faster? substr() or str_replace()?

Tags: php, substring, str-replace, substr

I have a script where I can use either `substr()` or `str_replace()`. With `substr()` I just have to cut off the last character and with str_replace I need to replace `!` with nothing. Which one would be faster?

I guess `substr()`?

Comment: As long as you're not calling that function in a 10000-loop or with a huge string, both take the same time...

Comment: You guess right. Why didn't you test? Also what @Martin said.

Comment: If, after testing you notice a significant difference between the two, please post your code and flag this to be re-opened.

Comment: you could also use
`$str = rtrim($str, '!');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the PHP source code, but I assume definitely `substr()`, as it can jump directly to the defined offset.

Don't forget though that this will make a difference only with lots of data. For smaller strings, it is preferable to choose whatever makes for more readable code.